# Is there a way to divide artifacts between test and compile using the maven-dependency-plugin during the copy-dependencies goal?

Tags: configuration, maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I have the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>analyze</id>
          <goals>
              <goal>analyze-only</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
      <!--Copy the dependencies so ant build has the same versions-->
      <execution>
          <id>copy-dependencies</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
              <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The above configuration dumps everything on the same folder. I tried excluding the test scope by adding the test configuration but gives an error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) on project pcgen:  Can't exclude Test scope, this will exclude everything.

Is there a way to separate test dependencies from the rest so I can copy to different folders?

Comment: Why do you want to do? why not using Maven directly instead of Ant ?

Comment: Just a requirement out of my control. Right now the project is migrating from ANT to Maven and I need to keep both running while the migration is complete. I'm trying to recreate their set up with Maven.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I tried excluding the test scope by adding the test configuration but gives an error

I just stumbled across this, probably for very different reasons, but I think I found us both the answer. Try this, for example. You'll need pom.xml in the current directory, of course.

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies \
-DincludeScope=runtime \
-DexcludeScope=provided \
-DoutputDirectory=target/war/WEB-INF/lib
```

A huge belated thanks to Brian Fox, who writes on [Maven Dependency Plugin Issue #128](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-128):

> You shouldn't ever need to include or exclude two scopes at the same time because they are comprised of each other. The default is to include test scope, which includes everything. If you don't want any test dependencies or provided dependencies, then include runtime and exclude provided.
>
> The scopes being interpreted are the scopes as maven sees them, not as specified in the pom. So the "test" scope includes everything, runtime includes compile but not provided etc.

In May 2013, the [includeScope documentation was updated](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=r1481514) to:

```
/**
  * Scope to include. An Empty string indicates all scopes (default).
  * The scopes being interpreted are the scopes as
  * Maven sees them, not as specified in the pom. In summary:
  * <ul>
  * <li><code>runtime</code> scope gives runtime and compile dependencies,</li>
  * <li><code>compile</code> scope gives compile, provided, and system dependencies,</li>
  * <li><code>test</code> (default) scope gives all dependencies,</li>
  * <li><code>provided</code> scope just gives provided dependencies,</li>
  * <li><code>system</code> scope just gives system dependencies.</li>
  * </ul>
  * 
  * @since 2.0
  */
 @Parameter( property = "includeScope", defaultValue = "" )
 protected String includeScope;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `includeScope` indeed, test scope includes every scope, that is why fails.

```
<includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
```